# Please solve the error in AWS CLI {Parameter validation failed}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

```
 aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ourfirsttest --region us-east-1 --template-body file://test.yml
```

Upon running the above command I get this error below.
I also have the 'test.yml' file in the current working directory

> Parameter validation failed:
>   Invalid length for parameter TemplateBody, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf

**Screenshot of the error**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Please post the cloudformation file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template file is empty.

If it wasn't empty you'd get a different error message.

When I have an empty file I receive the same error you did:

> Parameter validation failed:
>   Invalid length for parameter TemplateBody, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf

When I have a file with random characters in it the error message is:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.

If the `template-body` file is missing you receive another type of error message:

> Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load paramfile file://blahx.yml: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blahx.yml'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your template file is malformed.

I would first validate the template using the CLI command.

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://test.yml
```

Comment: your suggestion works but that was when i had corrected my poorly formatted .tml file